# Session sharing between two CodeIgniter Applications

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have 2 codeigniter installs running on the same server.

the first app is :
localhost/aa/index.php 
second app is : 
localhost/aa/invoice/index.php

The second app is in the first app folder. In the live environment, they will be on the same domain. I am trying to get a single sign-on to work -- so, if i have userdata set in the aa application I should be able to verify it in the invoice folder also.

Is there a way to share the sessions.

As the folders will always be on the same domain, I am open to working with sessions outside the ci library(only php) also.

**Edit :** 
They show the same session id when they don't have any data. The moment I add some variables on one application, the other goes out of sync.

Also I have sessions being stored in the database(both applications share the same database.)

Please suggest.

Thanks! : )

Comment: I don't know CodeIgniter, but look if there is a setting to specify the cookie path, and if there is, set the cookie path to `/aa/` (the folder of the first app, without the `localhost` part). Also look if there is a sessions dir, and set it (in the second app) to the first app session dir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Codeigniter for some reason rolls its own session implementation rather than native PHP sessions.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

You get a choice of using:

1. cookie storage (not ideal, small storage size, sensitive data in a cookie?).
2. database sessions (persisted using session id cookie).
3. Override and roll your own (to use native php sessions!)

Obviously you need to make sure your session identifier is configured correctly so both apps can read from the same session data. If using the database implementation, you need to make sure both apps can access the same DB.

To add to the complexity, if you choose to encrypt sessions, the salt used by the encryption class will also need to be the same in both apps, so either one is able to decrypt the shared session data.

Comment: one thing you will need to think of is if one app clears the session when the other shouldn't. I personally would pick option #3, and roll your own db table to manage it.

Comment: Using databases for session data (depending on individual application use case) is a performance killer. I've personally used native php sessions in a high traffic, multi-server setup without problems. Why re-invent the wheel? Admittedly, this is out of scope of the original question. One of the reasons I no longer use Codeigniter.

Comment: PHP sessions are getting propagated on both apps, will move in that direction. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'epitome';
```

The `encryption_key` configuration name will be the same for both the application folders.

Path to change the `encryption_key` in codeigniter is `application/config/config.php` Line number 228.

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'myvalue';
```

In config.php file you can set the same value on both CI Apps., with 'file' Session Drivers

```
CI_Session Object
```

(
    [userdata] => Array
        (
            [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1490351129
            [Level] => 1
            [User] => 103
            [Fullname] => Ruben Caldera
        )

```
[_driver:protected] => files
[_config:protected] => Array
    (
        [cookie_lifetime] => 600
        [cookie_name] => MyHiddenValue
        [cookie_path] => /
        [cookie_domain] => 
        [cookie_secure] => 
        [expiration] => 600
        [match_ip] => 
        [save_path] => /tmp
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

If I may ....
I have noted that those design problems which are not practical and goes against the normal convention shall provided a basis for long and deep rooted problems.... You should ask your self it is really necessary / advisable to share session data between 2 different version of a framework when we know they are 2 different version for the reason that they do things differently...
I can only say that no matter what you do.. this design flaw shall make your architecture fragile and sooner or later you will have to dump it.

Plz let me know if later you find out otherwise..

Comment: :) I'm a little more optimistic. It's going to have a set of its own problems, but basically we are just integrating a custom application with an existing CI project, not the ideal situation, but making it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the code on the same Server using the same encryption key, By default, both installation will share session. Actually, I discovered when I copied a codeigniter installation for another client but on the same server. I thought it was a bug as I was worried.

Answer (score -2):

If you move the code to the same server ,both the sessions will start to share by default.