# Extends CI native library into a package

Tags: shared-libraries, codeigniter-2

I'm developing a php application using CodeIgniter2, this application resides in:

```
/public_html/community/
 -application
 -system
 -index.php
```

This application has its own `My_Session` library (extending from native CI_Session library). Well, everything goes fine here. But, I want to create a Portal/Frontpage at the root directory, for this porpusee I have installed another CI2 application:

```
/public_html/
 -application
 -system
 -index.php
 -community/  (here resides the another CI2 installation)
```

What I have tried to do is "share" the Session library from `community` to root using the method [$this->load->add_package_path()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) from Loader class, as below:

```
$this->load->add_package_path('/public_html/community/application/');
$this->load->library('Session');
```

The problem here is that the Loader class load the Session library from the root system instead package library (community/application/libraries). Did you know how can I deal with it? or if you know a another way to share the Session Library.

### Edit

Here is where my session library resides:

```
/public_html/community/application/libraries/My_Session.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got with help of this topic: [Session sharing between two CodeIgniter Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502748/session-sharing-between-two-codeigniter-applications). And the final snipped is:

1. **Add the application package**

   $this->add_package_path('/public_html/community/application/');
2. **Load the Session library from Root CI application**

   $this->library('session');
3. **Load the library from the application package (community)**.
   The magic here is that this class extends from Session class previously 
   loaded at point 2.

   $this->library('MY_Session', '', 'csession'); //rename the object to avoid name conflict

Now, in my root application controllers I can do:

```
$this->csession->custom_method();
```