# Create session one application to another application using curl in php

Tags: php, session, curl, session-cookies

I have placed one codeigniter application in codigniter folder. Here is my folder structure.

```
application1
 application/
 system/
 assets/
 html/
 application2/
   application/
   system/
   assets/
   html/
```

My requirement is that once I logged-in into application1, I want to automatically set the session into another application (application2 as mentioned above structure). For this I am using curl. Here is my code.

```
   $url = "http://example.com/application2/home/login";

    //$requesturi = preg_replace('/[.|?|&]PHPSESSID=[^&]+/', "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $curl_PHPSESSID = 'PHPSESSID='.$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'].'; path=/sitespy/cookies.txt';
    $postdata       = "username=".$email."&password=".$userPassword."&apiRequest=1&PHPSESSID=".$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
    //set session for sitespy
    $ch = curl_init();

    session_start();

    session_write_close();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");

    $curl_cookies = session_name().'='.session_id().'; path=/'.base_url()."sitespy/cookies.txt";
    $cokkie_path  = base_url()."sitespy/cookies.txt";

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $curl_PHPSESSID);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $curl_cookies);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cokkie_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    echo $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Right now I am able to set the session on login page of application2 but when I trying to access another page i am not able to get that session from another section. Please anybody let me know there is possibility for that.

Comment: are both the applications on the same server ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502748/session-sharing-between-two-codeigniter-applications