# How To Use Same Session For Two Codeigniter Applications

Tags: php, authentication, session, codeigniter-3, session-cookies

I have two Codeigniter Application in Same server, But different databases.

Like
App 1 : mydomain.com
App 2 : mydomain.com/app

Is it possible to use App 1 Session Data in App2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session sharing between two CodeIgniter Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502748/session-sharing-between-two-codeigniter-applications)

Comment: @Nawin Thankyou for quick response, in my case i'm using **2 different DB's for 2** App's...

Comment: Look into your config file. If i remember right both needs to use the same `encryption_key` and `sess` and `cookie` vars